# CSS Upward Ribbon

Tags: html, css

So basically I'm creating a navigation bar (seen below) and I want to know if it's possible to create an upward ribbon type of thing.

[image]

Ignore the badly designed rest of the navigation, but I simply want the right part, the upward ribbon. Is it possible to do so, and preferably without images? I'm fine working with them, but I prefer it without.

Any help would gladly be appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. It is pure HTML and CSS, and you can change the bar and ribbon height.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLB7f/1/)

[image: screenshot]

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='bar'>This is the bar</div>
    <div id='corner'><div id='ribbon'></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS (I have explained how I got all the numbers in `/* comments */`)

```
#bar {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px; /* bar height */
}
#corner {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 30px solid blue; /* bar height */
    border-right: 30px solid transparent; /* bar height */
    float: left;
}
#ribbon {
    height: 10px; /* ribbon height */
    margin-top: -40px; /* bar height + ribbon height */
    background-color: green;
    width: 30px; /* bar height */
}
#wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px; /* ribbon height + 10px padding */
}
```

Comment: You can also try this for the inset box-shadow: `#ribbon { box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 15px -5px #000; }`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLB7f/2/)

Comment: Erm, I do. It's quite subtle though.

Comment: @ajbeaven Ah, after looking very closely I see it too :P It's very small though and I doubt the OP cares about it.

Comment: Probably more obvious if it's a navbar that spans the entire screen though. http://i.stack.imgur.com/pF0kK.png